# Probability of exponential of brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

$W_t$ is a brownian motion, I have this exponential value: $$v(t)= e^{0.00025 + 0.3W_t}$$  what's the probability that $v(1)<0.5$?

By taking natural log on both size, I got $0.00025 + 0.3W_1 < -ln(2), W_1 = -2.3$ 
Then the question becomes $$P(W_1<-2.3) =?$$

Comment: This is very easy it you took any basic probability course. What are your difficulties? Add more details to your question if you want it well received by the community :-)

Comment: Since $W_1$ has a continuous distribution, the probability is $0$.

Comment: @Ant  I don't know how to value probability of a brownian motion

Comment: @HowDoIMath My bad, it should be less than 0.5 not equal to 0.5.

Comment: The Brownian motion at a fixed time is just a random variable which is normally distributed. so you compute $P(W_1 < 2.3)$ in the same way as you would with a normally distributed random variable $\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check from the definition of a Brownian motion that $W_1$ has the normal distribution $N(0,1)$. So the problem really amounts to figuring out what

$$P(W_1<-2.3)$$

is for a standard normal random variable $W_1$. You can look this up in a table. You have that

$$P(W_1<-2.3) = \Phi(-2.3),$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: I am guessing that $\phi(-2.3) < 2.5% $ since its more than 2 standard deviation away from the mean?

Comment: @Dreamer That's true.